# Проблема termcolor colored python3 в консоли

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль, pyinstaller

Я написал такой код на Python  3.7.7

```
from termcolor import colored

print(colored("lalalala_gagagag", "cyan"))

print(colored("http://google.com", "cyan"))
```

При запуске её через PyCharm он выдаёт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(прошу прощения за то, что скрин, при копировании не сохраняется цвет)

Но при запуске через консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[36mlalalala_gagagag[0m
[36mhttp://google.com[0m
```

colorama тоже не работает.
Я скомпилировал в ехе при помощи PyInstaller. Проблема никуда не делась.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете помочь как это исправить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в стандартной кодировке консоли. По умолчанию, она однобайтовая. Вроде бы ASCII. Чтобы появились цвета, нужно изменить ее на двухбайтовую. Такими являются cp1251, unicode, .. . И очень странно, что colorama не изменяет кодировку. Она оборачивает терминал, изменяя его кодировку. Возможно вы не инициализировали ее (colorama.init)?[image: пример]

Comment: Дело не в кодировке консоли, а в том что консоль windows не поддерживает [ascii-последовательности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Управляющие_последовательности_ANSI). colorama добавляет эту поддержку (по сути перехватывает вывод программы, разбирает последовательности, меняет цвет в консоли средствами WinAPI).

Comment: * ANSI-последовательности, не ASCII